# django+bootstrap: concatentating bootstrap_alert

Tags: python, django, twitter-bootstrap-3, django-templates

I have the following code:

```
{% if errmsg %}
    {% bootstrap_alert errmsg alert_type='danger' %}
{% endif %}
```

`errmsg` is supplied from the previous page

I would like to extend the `errmsg` with some strings i.e.

```
{% if errmsg %}
    {% bootstrap_alert "msg: %s" % errmsg alert_type='danger' %}
{% endif %}
```

Obvously, the above prints error:

```
Could not parse the remainder: '%' from '%'
```

what is the correct way to print message for bootstrap_alert?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `str % ..` in Django template tag. Pass the formatted string from the view.

template:

```
{% if errmsg %}
    {% bootstrap_alert errmsg alert_type='danger' %}
{% endif %}
```

view:

```
context = {
    ...
    'errmsg': ('msg: ' + errmsg) if errmsg else errmsg,
    ...
}
```

Alternatively, if the string format is not complex, but just adding a string, you can use [`add` builtin filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/builtins/#add):

```
{% if errmsg %}
    {% bootstrap_alert 'msg: '|add:errmsg alert_type='danger' %}
{% endif %}
```